# how to connect two pcs using rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Python27/Scripts/send.py", line 4, in <module>
    host='192.168.1.11'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
ConnectionClosed
```

This is the error I'm getting when I'm connecting two laptops using rabbitmq. I gave the ipaddress in place of local host.

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host='ip address of receiver'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                  routing_key='hello',
                  body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code that you used which caused this error?

Comment: not enough details here. Some code, where is the server, can you telnet, what user....

Comment: Updated the question.